# What issues do you consider when designing a hash function?

Tags: function, hash

I am not looking for links to information on hashing.

I am not looking for the worlds greatest hash function.

I am interested in mini-stories describing

- The problem domain you were working in
- The nature of the data you were working with
- What your thought process was in designing a hash function for your data.
- How happy were you with your result.
- What you learned from the experience that might be of value to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing data warehouse development.  We had a dimension with about 9,000 rows.  The queries that were being developed included some really ugly queries.

So, I started analyzing the dimension rows.  Dimension rows were clustered based on various combinations of columns.  The clustering was a map from some key to a list of dimension rows that shared that key.  The hash key, then, was a tuple of column values.

The intermediate result, in Python, looked like this

```
{ 
    ( (col1, col2), (col3, col4) ) : [ aRow, anotherRow, row3, ... ],
    ( (col1, col2), (col3, col4) ) : [ row1, row2, row3. row4, ... ],
}
```

Technically, this is an inverted index.

The hash key required some care in building a tuple of column values, partly because Python won't use mutable collections (i.e., lists).  More important, the tuples weren't simple flat lists of column values.  They were usually two-tuples that attempted to partition the dimension rows into disjoint subsets based on key combinations

The hash algorithm, down deep, is the built-in Python hash.  Choosing the keys, however, wasn't obvious or easy.

Answer (score 9):

The first issue I consider is whether an established algorithm will suit my requirements.

Comment: Some questions that may help determine suitability:
Are collisions acceptable?
Should the hash be reversible?
Does the hash need to be continuous?

Answer (score 1):

i'll second what Adam said: don't reinvent the hashing wheel

the only time i have ever needed a custom hashing function was to compare digraphs for equality; the hashing function let me tell very efficiently when two graphs were *not* equal (when the hash values matched i still had to do a node-by-node comparison to be certain)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I think of is the best place to `steal` a hashing algorithm and its code.  If and only if I find no algorithm appropriate, I use them as a starting point to create my own.  To be fair, I have been in this industry for 7 years, and I have *never* created my own hashing algorithm since college.
But if I did create my own algorithm, minimizing collisions should be the biggest thing to think about.  What are your likely values?  Does this function accurately disperse those values so that hopefully there is a one to one relationship between the resulting value and the original value.  Do the resulting values really disperse well.  Meaning that say, they don’t all have common factors?  This could cause collisions when you do modulus operations to make the value smaller and fit into your indexed collection.

Answer (score 1):

Inventing a hashing algorithm is easy. Inventing a *working*, *efficient*, and *effective* hashing algorithm is not.

You should ask yourself:

1. Do I need to have a hash at all?
2. Assuming I do then implement a standard cookbook recipe (e.g. Effective Java) including *all* related requirements (e.g. if a.equals(b) then a.hashCode() == b.hashCode())

If you have two instances of an object that need to be compared for equality, then you probably need to provide an implementation for equals().

If you have multiple instances of an object that need to be sorted, then you probably need to provide an implementation for compareTo().

If you have a custom object being used as the key of a Map, then you probably need to provide an implementation of hashCode().

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly my experience, but some of the conditions you have to consider:

1. Most importantly hash function should be analogous to equality checking. Two equal objects should always always return the same hash (Two unequal objects can return same hash but that should be rare).
2. Better go for existing hash functions since they most probably will have better balance between speed and distribution.
3. Hashing function should be fast. Do not make it any bit slower/complex if the resulting hash wont yield in substantially better distribution of values. *So hashes of numeric types is always better* (agreed most frameworks have hashes of integer types, just saying).
4. Hashes should have good distribution that chances of collision has to be very less. XOR is a bad choice mostly hence. *In other words finding a good balance between speed and distribution is the key*. Chances are likely to have a slower hash if distribution is better.
5. Write the function knowing what size your output will be. If it is `int32` then ensure overflow doesn't happen.
6. Hashing function should never give an error (other than for null reference which is valid). The main culprit will be integer overflows. Handle it.
7. If you know before runtime itself what your possible inputs will be, then have a function to target that to speed up things.
8. Most probably hashes need not be reversible, but if ever you need it (say get the two numbers back from a given hash), write it accordingly. This may not be a requirement in general cases (where hashes collide).
9. If your hashes are just meant for quickly comparing two objects, then don't use it for security purposes. *[Cryptographic hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) is entirely a different beast.*
10. If you have more than one hashing functions at hand, then run quick test to find which operates better for your inputs. Testing will be always better than theoretically analyzing.

These are what I have off the top of my head. See [Eric's blog additionally](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx).